# Why is my HTML text not changing with this JS?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var goldCounter = document.getElementById("goldcounter");
var goldGenerator = document.getElementById("goldgenerator");
var gold = 0;
var goldperclick = 1;
goldCounter.innerHTML = 0;
function goldclick() {
goldCounter.innerHTML = gold + goldperclick;
}
goldGenerator.addEventListener("click", goldclick());
```

I used this JS code to try to set the text of my HTML paragraph to the value of gold every time the button is clicked, but the text stays at 1. Why?

Thanks everyone it works now! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the function and passing the result of that to the handler. You need to just pass the function without calling it.

You also need to actually increment the gold you're looking for, otherwise it's always `innerHTML = 0 + 1`.

```
function goldclick() { 
   gold += goldperclick;
   goldCounter.innerHTML = gold;
}
```

and

```
goldGenerator.addEventListener("click", goldclick);
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to increment the gold variable. It is always at 1 because you are assigning the result of the addition to the element.

```
function goldclick() { 
   //Add this
   gold += goldperclick;
   goldCounter.innerHTML = gold


}
```

Comment: Or more accurately, since the gold variable should increase by gold per click:

gold = gold + goldperclick;
goldCounter.innerHTML = gold;

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in this line:

```
 goldGenerator.addEventListener("click", goldclick());
```

It should be

```
 goldGenerator.addEventListener("click", goldclick);
```

You should be passing the function `goldclick` into `addEventListener`.

What your code is currently doing is calling `goldclick`, and passing the result of this function into `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
goldGenerator.addEventListener("click", goldclick());
```

to this

```
goldGenerator.addEventListener("click", goldclick);
```

You want to pass `goldClick` as a callback, not the result of the function call.